# Is that possible to download zoom recording from shared link programmatically? (javascript)

Tags: reactjs, download, zoom-sdk

everyone.
I have a shared link for zoom cloud recording.

I want to download the recording and play it on my react app.

I have only the shared link. No others like meeting_id, access_token, download_url, download_token.

Is that possible?

Thanks.